# Updating ecommerce transaction flaw

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

So i have following situation going:

1. User makes purchase request (**And transaction is sent to google
   analytics with 0 value**).
2. After some time Operator confirms purchase (**And transaction is updated and revenue is set to according amount**)
3. This works like a charm so far. **The Problem** is the fact that when updated transaction is sent, it also, somehow, updates where transaction was sent from. for ex... if referral user made a purchase, before update i can see transactions next to referral users but after update it disappears from there since operator is not referral user. this is just one downside. Next being the fact that website has two domains, but one actual website, so if user made a transaction from domain2, after operator updates transaction, i cant see it in the "domain2 view" since operators log in "domain1".

so, how can i make it so that only revenue updates and it doesnt touch anything else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be programing related.  may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Its not a transaction until its a completed transaction. You are making this more complicated then it needs to be. If you need to track all "attempts" separately then set that up as a "goal" in google analytics. Look up google analytics goal for how to do it. Then you can compare the attempts to transactions.

Comment: But the problem is that im only interested in transactions that come from referral users. I indeed can set up a goal and see attempts made by referral users but as for transaction i dont have segmented data, and im unable to see transactions from coming from referral users only overall transactions. As i said the fact that operator updates transactions causes transactions to disappear from referral section.